# PHP get the value of POST array with variable

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have a form with 30 inputs marked up like this...

```
<input type="number" class="qty" name="qty[adir_chair]"
```

How do I retrieve the value of the input in PHP? I have tried...

```
if ($_POST['qty'][adir_chair] > 0) {
```

... but this is breaking the page.

Comment: how is it braking the page and what do you want to do?

Comment: It shows a warning, I presume. It should be `$_POST['qty']['adir_chair']` - note quotes in second key.

Comment: Why did someone downvote my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create name of array so try

`if ($_POST['qty']['adir_chair'] > 0) {`

It works.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

While you are using array with keys then on every key you should put quotes like this

```
if ($_POST['qty']['adir_chair'] > 0) {
 //Things to do here
}
```

and it will works for you on every situation